# Is there a way for me to trigger the in-app purchase in portrait mode?

Tags: android, google-pay

After launching our application on the page, we encountered an issue where our users are unable to add their cards to the billing system using Google Play dialog. This problem arises because our application only supports landscape mode, which makes it difficult for buyers to enter their card number properly. Is there a way to display the dialog in portrait mode instead?

[image]